# TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out-Api testing

Tags: python, api, python-requests, gitlab, python-behave

I am trying to run python behave feature file in python for API testing. The code works fine in Pycharm but not in Gitlab CI. It shows

Given Set Get Route api endpoint as /api/Tourist/26  # steps/stepImplementation.py:15
When we send GET HTTP Status request to api          # steps/stepImplementation.py:21
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
raise err
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
      httplib_response = self._make_request(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
      self._validate_conn(conn)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
      conn.connect()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect
      self.sock = conn = self._new_conn()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 179, in _new_conn
      raise ConnectTimeoutError(
  urllib3.exceptions.ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9936df5150>, 'Connection to kyc.api.prev.validatis.de timed out. (connect timeout=None)')
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
      resp = conn.urlopen(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
      retries = retries.increment(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
      raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
  urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kyc.api.prev.validatis.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /validatis/v1.16.0 (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9936df5150>, 'Connection to ---------- timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
  
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1329, in run
      match.run(runner.context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/behave/matchers.py", line 98, in run
      self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
    File "steps/stepImplementation.py", line 23, in step_impl
      context.response = requests.get(context.url)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
      return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
      return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
      r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 507, in send
      raise ConnectTimeout(e, request=request)
  requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='kyc.api.prev.validatis.de', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ------ (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9936df5150>, 'Connection to ----------- timed out. (connect timeout=None)'))
Then The valid response of status code be 200        # None
```

Gitlab yml file

image: "python:3.10"

before_script:

- python --version
- pip install -r requirements.txt

stages:
- test

python_behave_tests:

```
stage: test
script: 
   - cd features
   - behave  TestApi.feature  --no-capture
   - behave  GetApiOperationModeStatus.feature  --no-capture
```

Is it the problem with my code or with the yml file or gitlab CI. But my code works in local environment.